# WPF/UWP: What is the difference between DependencyObject's GetValue() and ReadLocalValue()?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm a WPF developer. I'm curious to know, what is the difference between the `GetValue` and `ReadLocalValue` methods for `DependencyObject`? I know that `GetValue` can be used to implement a dependency property, like this:

```
public static DependencyProperty FoobarProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Foobar),
         typeof(int),
         typeof(DeclaringClass),
         new PropertyMetadata(0, OnFoobarChanged));

public int Foobar
{
     get { return (int)GetValue(FoobarProperty); }
     set { SetValue(FoobarProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnFoobarChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var newValue = (int)e.NewValue;
    // do something with the new value...
}
```

In a simple explanation, what purpose does `ReadLocalValue` serve? All I can garner from the [MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.readlocalvalue#examples) is that it may return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, which doesn't really tell much.

Comment: See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx) for the possible sources of dependency property values. The article also mentions "local values", and after reading it should be obvious what ReadLocalValue does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be about it. For the most part, yes, it is used to

> Return the local value, or return the sentinel value `UnsetValue` if no local value is set.

According to MSDN [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.readlocalvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

> You should use GetValue for most typical "get" operations for a dependency property. ReadLocalValue does not return the effective value for a variety of circumstances where the value was not locally set.
>
> Values that are set by styles, themes, templates, the default value from metadata, or property value inheritance are not considered to be local values. However, bindings and other expressions are considered to be local values, after they have been evaluated.
>
> When no local value is set, this method returns UnsetValue.
>
> If the returned value is other than UnsetValue, you can query the metadata of the requested dependency property to determine whether there is a more specific type that the return value can be converted to.